# Show results of SSH command executed with JSch in separate console/cmd window, not in IDE console

Tags: java, ssh, jsch

I am connecting to SSH in Java with JSch jar. And need to show result in cmd not in IDE console view. Any guidance for this, it is possible to open a command prompt with the result?

Why we need result in `cmd` means we need to take screenshot of the Command prompt window and send to client.

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;
import com.jcraft.jsch.Channel;
import com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelExec;
import com.jcraft.jsch.JSch;
import com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException;
import com.jcraft.jsch.Session;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class Putty1 {

   public static String txt;
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JSchException, FileNotFoundException {
        // TODO code application logic here


        String host="HostName";
        String user="xxxx";
        String password="xxxx";
        String command1="ls -ltr";
        try{

            java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties(); 
            config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
            JSch jsch = new JSch();
            Session session=jsch.getSession(user, host, 22);
            session.setPassword(password);
            session.setConfig(config);
            session.connect();
            System.out.println("Connected");

            Channel channel=session.openChannel("exec");
            ((ChannelExec)channel).setCommand(command1);
            channel.setInputStream(null);
            ((ChannelExec)channel).setErrStream(System.err);

            InputStream in=channel.getInputStream();
            channel.connect();
            byte[] tmp=new byte[1024];
            while(true){
              while(in.available()>0){
                int i=in.read(tmp, 0, 1024);
                if(i<0)break;

                    txt = new String(tmp, 0, i);

                System.out.print(txt);




              }
              if(channel.isClosed()){
                System.out.println("exit-status: "+channel.getExitStatus());
                break;
              }
              try{Thread.sleep(1000);}catch(Exception ee){}
            }
            channel.disconnect();
            session.disconnect();
            System.out.println("DONE");
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //System.out.println(txt);
        try (PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("C:\\Documents and Settings\\arahman9\\My Documents\\Downloads\\jpp\\prs72760.txt")) 
        {
            out.println(txt);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Connected
total 12
drwxrwxrwt  2 arahman9 arahman9 4096 Jul 10 14:30 tmp
drwxr-xr-x  2 arahman9 arahman9 4096 Jul 10 14:30 public_html
drwxr-xr-x  2 arahman9 arahman9 4096 Jul 10 14:30 Documents
exit-status: 0
DONE
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 2 seconds)
```

Comment: What does it mean *"in cmd not in console"*?

Comment: that means not in IDE console I required in CMD

Comment: What do you mean about sending a screenshot to a client? Where is the client in this system? Do you need a screenshot specifically or just the output of the program as text?

Comment: Actually the output I required in Command prompt, instead in console log, so could you help me in this

Comment: How are you launching your program? The "Command Prompt" application and the "Console" tool window in your IDE are both consoles. Which one your program is connected to depends on how the program is lanuched.

Comment: I am using netbeans IDE

Comment: @VyTcdc: Yes, but how are you launching the program? It sounds like you have a fundamental misunderstanding of how programs communicate with consoles, but I don't know how to explain unless I know how much you do understand. Do you know what `stdin`/`stdout`/`stderr` are? Do you understand what the "Command Prompt" application on Windows does (as opposed to `CMD.EXE`, which runs inside it)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177106/discussion-between-vytcdc-and-daniel-pryden).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you execute a console application in IDE (Eclipse/Netbeans/etc), IDE redirects console application output to Console view.

But if you run your application in `cmd.exe` it will use `cmd.exe` console.

And if you run your application directly (via `java.exe`), e.g. from Windows Run box, it will create its own console window.

That's just how console application behave. It has nothing to do with your code.

Also, here's some trick that can be used to make Eclipse not redirect console application output to Console view:
https://www.reddit.com/r/eclipse/comments/1bk7a1/how_do_i_run_programs_in_a_separate_console_window/